# Do optical filters emit thermal radiation at filtered frequencies?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, thermal-radiation

So as the title says. Do optical filters emit thermal radiation at frequencies they are supposed to block or at frequencies they are supposed to let trough? Or does their spectral absorption property have no effect on their thermal radiation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By [Kirchoff's law of thermal radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_law_of_thermal_radiation), the emissivity of an object is equal to its absorbtivity.

That means that things are strong emitters at wavelengths where they are also strong absorbers.

If your filter is a reflective one, reflecting light in its stop-band and transmitting light in its pass-band, then it won't (ideally) be a strong absorber in either band, so it won't be a strong emitter either.

If your filter works by absorbing light in its stop-band, then it will be a good emitter in that band also.

But remember, emissivity is the ratio of the objects emission to that of an ideal black-body. Unless you are heating your filters to very high temperatures, you wouldn't expect them to emit very much in the near IR or visible range, even if they were perfect emitters.

Comment: Thank you. This is just what I was looking for. I am trying to make a product, which has a temperature IR sensor, which can measure trough 4 mm of glass temperatures ranging from 50 to 300 °C. Emisivity is not a problem because I Will calibrate it. But because of thermal radiation at those temperatures being very low at long wavelengths, I have to use some kind of filter, which let's only about 3-4 microns wavelength band. This way IR get's trugh glass and bodies already emit thermal radiation at those frequencies. But I have to make sure there woun't be interference by the filter itself. :P